# QML TreeView - Change position of expand icon

Tags: qt, treeview, qml

I'm currently trying to change the layout of a **QML TreeView** so that the **expand icon** (the arrow or triangle you have to click in order to show or hide the children elements).

I tried anchoring the icon to the right of the TreeView, but for some reason it's not working, it remains on the left despite everything. Do you have any hint?

Thanks a lot!

```
TreeView {
    id: treeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: treeModResult

    style: TreeViewStyle {
        branchDelegate: Rectangle {
            width: 15; height: 15
            color: "#00000000"
            anchors.right: treeView.right

            Image {
                id: expandArrow
                source: styleData.isExpanded ? "qrc:/img/icn_arrow_top.svg" : "qrc:/img/icn_arrow_bottom.svg"
                sourceSize.width: parent.width
                sourceSize.height: parent.height
            }

            ColorOverlay {
                anchors.fill: expandArrow
                source: expandArrow
                color: "#293147"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is what I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: I think it will be nice if you can provide 2 images - what you have and what you want.

Comment: Thank you @folibis, I added the two images as you suggested!

Comment: can you provide the treemodel cpp class as well ? i would like to implement something similar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I came up with the following solution, as anchoring wasn't working for me neither..

```
style: TreeViewStyle {
        branchDelegate: Rectangle{
            id: expandIcon
            x: control.width - width
```

control.width represents the width of the treeview.